# Why am I getting "Graph API access token failure: 'Group.Read.All'"

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to find out why I am getting the error ""Graph API access token failure: 'Group.Read.All'"

I have followed the guide "[Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly hosted app with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1)" and "[Azure Active Directory (AAD) groups, Administrator Roles, and user-defined roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0)" I can log in but I also gets errors that I don't want to have.

[image]

What I don't understand is where the Group.Read.All calls are coming from.

This is the HttpClient configuration used to call the MS Graph API

```
b.Services.AddHttpClient("GraphAPI",
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(provider => provider.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
                .ConfigureHandler(
                    authorizedUrls: new []{"https://graph.microsoft.com/"},
                    scopes: new []{"Group.Read.All"}
                ));
```

And used in the CustomUserFactory

```
{
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("GraphAPI");
var response = await client.GetAsync("v1.0/me/memberOf");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var userObjects = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<DirectoryObjects>();
    foreach (var obj in userObjects?.Values)
    {
        if(_appGroups.Contains(obj.DisplayName))
        {
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", obj.DisplayName));
            Console.WriteLine($"group {obj.DisplayName}");
        }
    }
    // var claim = userIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "hasgroups");
    // userIdentity.RemoveClaim(claim);
}
else
{
    _logger.LogError($"Graph API request failure: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
}
```

}

I have tried not to set "authorizedUrls" and "scopes" but then the login fails.
Again it works and I can read all groups on the logged in user. But I must obvious be doing something wrong.

Permissions set on the Azure AD for my Blazor WASM Client
[image]

Comment: The first link was broken, could you edit it?

Comment: if you check network logs in the browser (pressing F12) do you see any failures

Comment: No. So I tried with Fiddler and try to watch the https trafic, the result the login process stopped working.